# echo $user->roles[0]; in WordPress menu navigation

Tags: php, wordpress, navigation, shortcode

At the beginning I want to say that all the code presented below works well if put in right environment. I only have an issue with php in wordpress menu navigation that seems not to be able to work.

I'm trying to print user's role (there's only one role a user can have at a time) in a dropdown. PHP code:

```
<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
echo $user->roles[0];   ?>
```

dropdown code:

```
<ul id="primary-menu" class="navbar-nav ml-auto"><li class="nav-item    menu-item menu-item-type-gs_sim menu-item-object-gs_sim"><a href="" class="nav-link">(Untitled)<small class="description"></small></a><small class="description"><div class="dropdown show"><a href="" class="nav-link">
  </a><a class="nav-link btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <img src="http://ds.com/wp-content/uploads/ultimatemember/1/profile_photo-40x40.png?1561371663" class="gravatar avatar avatar-40 um-avatar um-avatar-uploaded" width="40" height="40" alt="pzo3xic" data-default="http://ds.com/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/img/default_avatar.jpg" onerror="if ( ! this.getAttribute('data-load-error') ){ this.setAttribute('data-load-error', '1');this.setAttribute('src', this.getAttribute('data-default'));}"> pzo3xic
  </a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu show" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <h6 class="dropdown-header" href="/user/">Paid Subscriber</h6>
<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="/profile">View Profile</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/private-lessons">Private Lessons</a>
<a class="dropdown-item" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
  </div>
</div></small></li>
<li class="nav-item    menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category"><a href="http://ds.com/lessons/" class="nav-link">Lessons</a></li>
<li class="nav-item    menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page"><a href="http://ds.com/tests/" class="nav-link">Tests</a></li>
</ul>
```

I want it to present as below (where "Paid Subscriber" is the user's role name):

[image: example]

But when I replace "Paid Subscriber" with my custom shortcode "[print_user_role]" it kind of displays the text instead of the function within. Let me point out here that my shortcode works well when added into other places.

[image: what's going on]

Problem:
The avatar along with dropdown are all in a code added via Shortcode in Menus plugin. This plugin (and all the others) don't support php inside.

I have tried adding a shortcode into my custom_functions.php, then invoking it by pasting [my_custom_function_sc] into the code, however it returned nothing.

I lost ideas on how to achieve this effect. Does any of you see a possible solution here?

***EDIT***
I think that I might actually print the user's role somewhere else within a certain block, then with jquery copy the text within the block and paste in place that interests me. Does any of you have any ideas on how to achieve this? I haven't used javascript/jQuery really.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct except this line --> echo $user->roles[0];

The correct code is --> echo $user->roles;

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out! I was lucky enough to have it work anyway, but yeah this version seem more correct.